# Getting the correct row position of JTree nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm working with Java's swing's JTree, and need to find the appropriate row index of the selected node within it's path. For example, when I select `Polygon 2` in the picture below,

[image]

-and use this piece of code,

```
tree.getRowForPath(/*path of polygon node*/);
```

-I get the value `2`, which is correct. However, when I select `Polygon 3`, I get the value `6`. This is because it takes the nodes that `Polygon 2` expanded into count when finding the appropriate node. I don't want this, as I need to return the value 3 when `Polygon 3` is selected, regardless if any or the nodes prior are expanded or not.

I thought of looping through all nodes, finding which ones are before the row index of the selected, seeing if they're expanded, and counting how many nodes they contain. Then add that to the row returned from the method above.

The issue is I don't know how to approach this. I have some attempted spaghetti code, but I doubt that's useful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess the question is why?  What is it you are trying to achieve that requires you have `3` as the result?  From the sounds of things, you can get the node without issue, why do you need the row value?  If you're using something like `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, you can supply a `userObject` which can contain additional information which might help you accomplish your goal

Comment: @MadProgrammer This JTree has nodes that change if a user adds or deletes a polygon. I have a separate ArrayList that contains the polygons, and based off of that, this JTree updates its list if something changes. If I want to select a polygon in the JTree, I need to know the row so I can make the connection to the ArrayList, and change whatever I want to that polygon. I think it would be easier if I had an algorithm that calculated that, rather than extending `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. I could be wrong.

Comment: My preferred solution would be to have `DefaultMutableTreeNode` manage the `Polygon` or have some reference to the model it can update, but that's me :P ... basically, you want to minimize the amount of cohesion there is between the `JTree` and your existing model

Comment: That's a really good point. I'll get started working on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a solution based off of @MadProgrammer's suggestion in his comment. I created a tree node class like so:

```
public class CustomTreeNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {

    private int position;

    public CustomTreeNode(String text, int position){
        super(text);
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return this.position;
    }

}
```

This allows me to hold the index of whatever object I want, regardless of the name (referencing @Sergiy Medvynskyy's also helpful solution).

I initialized the objects like so (this was in a for loop):

```
//root node
CustomTreeNode polygon = new CustomTreeNode("Polygon " + (i+1), i);
```

I used the nodes like this:

```
@Override
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {

    TreePath[] selectedPaths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
    TreePath parentPath = tree.getClosestPathForLocation(1, 1);

    if (selectedPaths == null)
        return;

    ArrayList<Integer> validRows = new ArrayList<>();

    for (TreePath tp : selectedPaths){

        if (tp.getParentPath() != parentPath)
            continue;

        //get node that current selected path points too, then get the custom index of that
        CustomTreeNode selectedNode = (CustomTreeNode) tp.getLastPathComponent();

        System.out.println(selectedNode.getPosition());

        validRows.add(selectedNode.getPosition());

}
```

Notice how I'm easily able to populate the ArrayList validRows without iterating over every node and eliminating the expanded ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of that, what you want (if I correctly understand your question), but the solution of @MadProgrammer is the preferred way.

```
public static int indexInParentForPath(JTree aTree, TreePath path) {
    Object p = null;
    Object parent = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < path.getPathCount(); i++) {
        if (path.getPathComponent(i).toString().contains("Polygon")) {
            p = path.getPathComponent(i);
            parent = i > 0 ? path.getPathComponent(i - 1) : null;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (p != null) {
        return parent == null ? 0 : aTree.getModel().getIndexOfChild(parent, p);
    }
    return -1;
}
```